# sqlcommand execute query not updating deleting and inserting

Tags: c#, sqlcommand, executenonquery

Hello i always use SQlcommand for non query but now something wrong i dont know what  i have 3 buttons with operations update insert and delete but i created unique method for all 3 operations, the problem is it doesn't insert delete or update:

```
private void operacao(String operacao) {
        String comando = "";
        con = new SqlConnection();
        WorksDataSet  dataset = new WorksDataSet();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Works.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Asynchronous Processing=true";
        try
        {
            con.Open();

        }
        catch (SqlException cox) {
            MessageBox.Show(cox.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        switch (operacao) { 
            case "inserir":

                try
                {
                    comando = "Insert Into Estudante (Codigo,Nome,Apelido) values(" + txtID.Text + ",'" + txtNome.Text + "','" + txtapelido.Text + "')";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comando, con);
                    SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    sda.Fill(dataset);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Dispose();
                    MessageBox.Show("Adicionado com Sucesso", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                catch (SqlException sex) {
                    MessageBox.Show(sex.Message , this.Text,MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error );
                }

                break;

            case "apagar":
                comando = "delete from Estudante where Codigo=" + txtID;
                try
                {

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comando, con);
                    command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Removido com Sucesso", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                catch (SqlException sex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(sex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                break;
            case "atualizar":
                comando = "update table Estudante set nome='" + txtNome + "'^ apelido='" + txtapelido + "'";
                try
                {

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comando, con);
                    command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Actualizado com Sucesso", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                catch (SqlException sex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(sex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break
                ;
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: why do you use BeginExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: wow..  catch (SqlException sex) and  MessageBox.Show(sex.Message... seems intersting.. :)

Comment: @Oldemiro: is it throwing any exception or its not going into switch case as you are using string in switch cases. so please confirm..?

Comment: have you checked your sql-statements direct? (for example in the sql management studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use parametrized query. ALWAYS.....

this for the insert op.

```
comando = "Insert Into Estudante (Codigo,Nome,Apelido) values(@id, @nome, @apelido");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comando, con);                     
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtID.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtNome.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apelido", txtapelido.Text);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                     
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

No need to use a dataset or a dataadapter here. just the ExecuteNonQuery

this for the delete op.

```
comando = "delete from Estudante where Codigo=@id";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comando, con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtID.Text);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Notice that you should pass the Text property, not the whole TextBox

this for the update op

```
comando = "update table Estudante set nome=@nome, apelido=@apelido where codigo=@id";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comando, con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtID.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtNome.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apelido", txtapelido.Text);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here also, use the Text property not the TextBox object

In this way you don't need to worry about quotes in your string params and you close the door to
[Sql Injection Attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: This is correct, but i don't think that this solves the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

To execute `insert/delete/update` statement, you just need to create `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` object. `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` are useless.

To insert a row:

```
string cnstr=@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Works.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Asynchronous Processing=true";

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnstr))
 {
  string sql = "Insert Into Estudante (Codigo,Nome,Apelido) values(@Codigo,@Nome,@Apelido)";
  using(SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand(sql,con))
   {
     command.Parameters.Add("@Codigo",SqlDbType.Int).Value=txtID.Text;
     command.Parameters.Add("@Nome",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value=txtNome.Text;
     command.Parameters.Add("@Apelido",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value=txtapelido.Text;
     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: nothing happen when i try to repeat a record it generates sqlException but when I visit Table with Explorer nothing has been modified;

Comment: Select .mdf file from solution explorer + open the properties windows to set `Copy To Output Directory=Copy if newer`

Comment: try
                    {
                        comando = "Insert Into Estudante (Codigo,Nome,Apelido) values(@ID,@Nome,@Apelido)";
                        
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comando, con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",txtID.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txtNome.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apelido", txtapelido.Text);
con.Open();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Adicionado com Sucesso", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the the sqlDataAtapter's Fill method to fill the database which is unnecessary. remove that statement and see. That should work.