# Delete from Database advice

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a C# delete function.  This is what I have so far, although I want to adapt it to work like my pseudo code below.

Pseudo code for new function

```
//public bool delete(Dictionary <string, string> id, string tableName)
//{

//reader or another object

//open conenction 

//statement takes input of the primary key of the row to be edited
//as an array of one, the value plus the name of the column representing the primary key
//for the row to be deleted, as well as the table name 


//connection

//excute 

//return bool? 

//}
//}
```

What I've tried:

```
public bool Delete(Dictionary <string, string> id, string tableName)
{            
    //reader or another object            

    //open connection 
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {    
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tableName WHERE id=id", conn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }              
    }
}
```

But when doing this I am struggling with adapting the code and would appreciate some help please.  I can provide more info if needed.  I want the new function to take the input of the unique identifier of the row to be edited as an array of one – the value plus the name of the column representing the primary key - for the row to be deleted, as well as the table name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Okay so the problem i am encountering is how to adjust my current code to fit the new purpose, the part  i am struggling with is the statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlcommand execute query not updating deleting and inserting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344528/sqlcommand-execute-query-not-updating-deleting-and-inserting)

Comment: All of your questions that I've seen so far are basic syntax questions.  Have you read the supporting documentation?  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233823.aspx) is pretty useful once you get used to reading it.  Questions about syntax which can easily be solved via a simple Google search are generally poorly received here, especially as there are many duplicates even here on this site.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your help, okay I will look at that now, although I think that these functions are slightly harder then the basic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the values from your arguments and put them into a correctly formatted sql string, like so:

```
public bool Delete(string id, string column, string table)
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
  {
     conn.Open();
     var query = String.Format("DELETE FROM {0} WHERE {1}='{2}'", table,column, id)
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
     {
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
  }
}
```

This approach has many performance and security issues, but I take it you are doing this for educational purposes?

Comment: Okay i will give that a go, yep i don't mind about that at this stage. It says not all code paths are returning a value so how would i return a boll en at the end to say that delete has worked?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, or make the method void for now.

Comment: The thing is i have to do it with  public bool Delete(Dictionary <string, string> id, string tableName) so I can't use that method but thanks for your help